# how to create a file and write some output to it from server side java script

Tags: javascript

I am new to java script. I have execute some API from server-side java script and stored their status in a array now i want to create a file at desired location on same machine and write output to it.

Comment: What kind of server-side javascript are you working with? `Node.js`? `.asc`? How is this server-side javascript currently running?

Comment: you have to define what framework you are using on server side

Answer (score 0):

You must have to use server-side language to do this js won't do that!

Lets take the example of the ASP.NET

```
@{
    var userData = /* data stored in the array */
    var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.txt"); // file location
    File.AppendAllText (@dataFile, userData); // save it!
}
```

This way, you will be able to save the data in the file on the server-side. If you wanted to save it without reloading the page (like many developers love to) then you can try using ajax request. For that, you will be using jQuery AJAX but still to write the data to a file you will require the server-side. Here

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'url/where/file_is.txt'
});
```

And the in page, you will have the server-side code which will

1. Get the array data
2. Split it relatively
3. Write it to the file.

This way you will have the user's data written to the file.

For more: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/files,-images,-and-media/working-with-files

If you're using PHP, you can do a Google search for that!

Comment: _"You must have to use server-side language to do this js won't do that!"_ - JavaScript _can_ be used server-side, and the OP said they're already using JS server-side, so why would you give an answer using another language? (Perhaps they're using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)?) _"For that, you will be using jQuery AJAX"_ - What? The OP isn't asking how to do Ajax, but even if they were they don't need jQuery to do it.